# Does the loss of mass create an observable change in a comet's orbit?

Tags: orbit, the-sun, comets

Comets lose their mass through water evaporation due to close encounter with sun, so my question is does the loss of mass create an observable change in a comet's orbit? What kind of change that may be shrinking orbit or expanding orbit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was studied in [Yu & Zheng (1995)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0256-307X/13/6/021/meta;jsessionid=EEAA7E4E254BA2B9226DD9D56C5C8404.c4.iopscience.cld.iop.org), who evaluated the effects of the change in the Sun's mass over time and the change in a comet's mass over time, for the case of [Shoemaker-Levy 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9), which had recently crashed into Jupiter. Given their mass model for the comet (Equation 6), they found that the Sun's mass loss created an increase in semi-major axis of about 8.5 centimeters per year, whereas the comet's mass loss created an increase in semi-major axis of about 10,000 kilometers per year.

Several things to note:

- The comet orbited Jupiter prior to breaking up, so it did not come as close to the Sun as most short-period comets.
- Mass loss rates can change over time, depending on the distance from the Sun.
- Shoemaker-Levy 9 should not be considered a normal comet, in any sense, given its orbit and eventual destruction.

10,000 kilometers a year, though, is nothing to sniff at. Over the course of an orbit, that can be quite a lot - although keep in mind that longer orbits involve much larger semi-major axes - and I'd argue that it should be observable, given the correct calculations of how the orbit should evolve over time.

Comment: Your answer is good in its own but not as specific as i asked.
What argument is right but you don't specifically mention that what kind of that change may be? 
My field is not astronomy so please bear with me.

Comment: Why does comet orbit change? Because the mass loss is asymmetric?

Comment: @ShujaatAliKhan The orbital parameter we're concerned with is the [semi-major axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes), one half the distance between the two furthest points in the elliptical orbit of the comet. It increases as the comet looses mass.

Comment: @RobJeffries It turns out that the mass loss of the comet causes a tangential acceleration perturbation, coming from matter being blown off the comet at a constant velocity.

Comment: So with every revolution a comet actually becomes more eccentric?  That is interesting.  If you wanted to cause the opposite and reduce the semi-major axis, I suppose you could 'block' the mass losses natural direction and only allow the opposite direction to be exposed to mass loss.